# How to solve Angular dilemma with dialogs?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have `DialogService` that has Factory method, depends specific component it creates dialog window.

```
@Injectable()
export class DialogService {

public factory(tableName: string, typeContent: typeContent) {
    this._typeContent = typeContent;

    switch (tableName) {
      case ETableNames.GeneralDictionary:
        this._component = DictionarySimpleDialogComponent;
        this._factory = new SimpleDictionaryClass(
          this.formBuilder,
          this.simpleDictService,
          this.localStorage
        );

        break;
     }

     this._factory.formBuilder(this._typeContent);
}

public open(
    dialogModel: IDialog,
    component?: Component
  ): Observable<boolean> {

    const config = {};
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(this._component, config);

    dialog.componentInstance["model"] = this._factory;

    return dialog.afterClosed();

    }

}
```

Problem is I can not use this service in specific component as inject:

```
export class DictionarySimpleDialogComponent {
  model: ClassificatorOrganizations;
  type: typeContent;
  constructor(
    private dialogService: DialogService, protected dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DictionarySimpleDialogComponent>
  ) {}

}
```

It  swears:

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'DialogService' before initialization
>  at Module../src/app/components/dialogs/dictionaries/dictionarySimple/dictionarySimpleWord-dialog.component.ts
> ```
>
> (dictionarySimpleWord-dialog.component.ts:15)

So, I can not create a new dialog window from exist dialog window. Probably this is issue of architecture.

Comment: My attempt is create different dialog windows depends incoming parameters

Comment: Could you add a StackBlitz Demo?